# Check if value in Scala Enumeration exists in an Array of Strings

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration like this:

```
object VersionTokens extends Enumeration {
  type VersionTokens = Value

  val ALL = Value("ALL")
  val CURRENT = Value("CURRENT")
}
```

Is there a way to check if any of the values in the enumeration exists in an array of strings?

**pseudo code:**

```
val versions = Array("CURRENT", "SOMETHING ELSE")
if(versions.contains(VersionTokens)) true
else false

// should return true since "CURRENT exists in the enumeration
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, for example, check if the value set of your enumeration intersects your array :

```scala
VersionTokens.values.map(_.toString).toArray.intersect(versions).nonEmpty
```

or, less readable but faster:

```scala
VersionTokens.values.map(_.toString).toArray.exists(versions.contains)
```